# Cannot accept XDomainRequest POST to WebAPI

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api, xdomainrequest

I have a controller class and I can initiate a Get call on the API but when I try a POST command I get HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Is there somewhere that I have to allow POST? I placed [HttpPost] in front of the method but no luck.

```
public class initController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        oTree myT = new oTree();
        myT.build(0);
        myT.entity.question = value;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myT);
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Javscript post code:

```
function gpRequest(service, verb, oData, callback) {
if (bool_cantransmit) {
    bool_cantransmit = false;
    var xdr;
    var url = base_service_url + service + "/";
    if (window.XDomainRequest) // Check whether the browser supports XDR. 
    {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Create a new XDR object.
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onerror = errorHandler;
            xdr.onload = callback;
            xdr.contentType = "application/json";
            xdr.open(verb, url);
            xdr.send(oData);
        }
    } else {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onerror = errorHandler;
        xhr.onload = callback;

        xhr.open(verb, url, true);
        xhr.send(oData);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly and how are you posting?

Comment: You may be setting the accept header to a type which your application can't support. Please show your post code.

Comment: I have added the javascript post code (would have been useful at the start :)

Comment: I am posting test data such as : value=Test

Comment: I was hoping that this would show in the method:  public string Post([FromBody]string value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `value=Test` is not a valid json. You could send a json format since you have setted `application/json` to the `content-type` header request property, for sample:

```
gpRequest(service, 'POST', "{ Value: 'Test' }", callback);
```

In the server side, try to create a DTO object:

```
public class MessageDTO
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And get in on the `post` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]MessageDTO message)
{
    oTree myT = new oTree();
    myT.build(0);
    myT.entity.question = message.Value;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works brilliantly. My only issue is catering for IE8/9 which is why I use XDomainRequest to handle cross origin issues. I understand that there is a bug in this that XDomainRequest cannot handle type application/json. Can I test for text/plain and convert it. Currently I get 415 if posting from XDomainRequest but works well on a REST test client

Comment: I think this might do it: http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/  ?

Comment: To anyone reading this. I cannot see how you can send JSON via POST to webapi as you cannot change the headers or contenttype. I have spent 2 days on this and have to conclude that it is not possible to work like this on IE<10 as IE<10 uses XDomainRequest and it is very badly implemented. Rememeber, this is CORS only

Answer (score 6):

After experiencing similar problems I decided to write this down for future reference.

The problem with `XDomainRequest` is that it doesn't add a `Content-Type` header.
This means that the `Content-Type` will default to `application/octet-stream` for which there are no default `MediaTypeFormatters`. This causes the API to reject the request with `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

One possible workaround is to assume that `application/octet-stream` is `application/json`.

Create a new `OctetStreamMediaFormatter` that derives from `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` but also accepts `application/octet-stream`:

```cs
public class OctetStreamMediaFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public OctetStreamMediaFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }
}
```

Add the new formatter to your configuration (e.g in `Global.asax.cs`)

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new OctetStreamMediaFormatter());
```

In your `ApiController` decorate the appropriate method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "POST")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExampleAction(ExampleModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`[EnableCors(...)]` adds the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response. Enable CORS (e.g. in `WebApiConfig.cs`):

```cs
config.EnableCors();
```

It should now be possible to send and receive data using `XDomainRequest`.

```
function xdr(json) {

    if (!window.XDomainRequest) {
        console.log("Sorry, XDomainRequest not supported");
        return;
    }

    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Sorry, XDomainRequest.onerror()");
    };
    xdr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xdr.responseText);
    };
    xdr.open("POST", "ExampleApiController/ExampleAction");
    xdr.send(json);

}
```

Comment: +10gazillion points, I've been reading and trying every option on the intawebz to try and get IE9 CORS working with json post data, you ROCK!

Comment: +11gazillion points. I thought default content-type for XDomainRequest was text/plain!!! I've created a TextPlainMediaFormatter and nothing. Now works in webapi 2. Many, many thanks!